# What does this error mean and why does it happen?

Tags: python

In this code:

```
import requests, pprint, re, gspread, time
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime
import oauth2client, httplib2
from oauth2client.file import Storage



def temperature():
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('Singapore-Weather-84def2be176a.json')
    credentials = storage.get()
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    credentials.refresh(http)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wks = gc.open('Singapore Weather').sheet1
    r = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b02b5107a2c9c27deaa3bc1876bcee81/1.312914,%20103.780257')
    json_object = r.json()


    regexCurrentTemp = re.compile(r'"temperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moTemp = regexCurrentTemp.search(str(json_object))
    temperature = moTemp.group(1)

    regexApparentTemp = re.compile(r'"apparentTemperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moApparent = regexApparentTemp.search(str(json_object))
    apparent = moApparent.group(1)

    current = json_object['currently']
    cloud = current['cloudCover']
    cloud *= 100

    timenow = datetime.now()
    wks.append_row([str(timenow), temperature, apparent, cloud])

while True:
    temperature()
    time.sleep(3597)
```

I am getting an error code related to one of the modules, which I do not know what it means. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rosen59250/PycharmProjects/MorningWeather/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    temperature()
  File "/Users/rosen59250/PycharmProjects/MorningWeather/main.py", line 12, in temperature
    credentials = storage.get()
  File "/Users/rosen59250/EvenorOdd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 407, in get
    return self.locked_get()
  File "/Users/rosen59250/EvenorOdd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/file.py", line 54, in locked_get
    credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(content)
  File "/Users/rosen59250/EvenorOdd/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 302, in new_from_json
    module_name = data['_module']
KeyError: '_module'
```

Why is this error code happening? Is there a way I can fix this, or is this a bug in the module?

If I can fix it, how could I?

Comment: You could try to insert a `print(data)` right before line 302 in client.py to see the contents of the dictionary. Although jufx' answer is not too helpful, he might be right about the missing key... ;)

Comment: I am pretty sure that client.py is just a file that is a part of oauth2client. It may be oauth2client.file. I think this because the code doesn't call the file

Comment: I'm a 100% sure you are right, and I didn't claim anything else. However, you still need to track down the error, right? So either (i) write everything yourself or (ii) use another package / import or (iii) try to fix the error. - Choose wisely.

Comment: Knock knock. - Who's there? - [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976129/google-api-v4-for-python-keyerror-module)

Comment: putting print(data) does nothing. I don't know how I would do it. I ran the client.py, it did nothing. I ran main.py (my script name) it did nothing.

Comment: Have you seen the thread I linked to above? Comments..? - If you insert a `print('here is client.py, data = ', data)` statement in client.py (located in the path visible in your error code - don't forget to save it and restart your python compiler), you MUST get something, because obviously, you call this function by calling `storage.get()`.

Comment: I saw, and that is just my json file. how could i add that correct thing in

Comment: You have to rename the credentials.json file to client_secret.json.

Comment: I don't have credentials.json. The name of the json is the one google gave me

Comment: `storage = oauth2client.file.Storage('Singapore-Weather-84def2be176a.json')` Can yu then give it an absolute path to `Singapore-Weather..`

Comment: I don't need to, because it is in the project file. I think the problem is that the json doesnt have _module, but I don't know the argument for it.

Comment: What version of oauth2client do you have as in the version i just downloaded `locked_get` doesnt actually implement anything.

Comment: In your json file have you defined `_module` and `_class` as these will be read from your json by oauth2client to decide what type of service_account instance to return you

Comment: but I dont have module and class in the json. I just have the default stuff google gave me

Comment: I used pip3 install oauth2client

Comment: Thats your issue, you are not using a valid json object serialised by this module for a credential object. you cant just give it any old json you have. I have added an answer which explains this

Answer (score 0):

there is no '_module' key in your data dict. Works for me using json authentication:

```py
pass_url='/my/json/pass.json'
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(pass_url, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

then client is able to open worksheets, append rows, etc.
Hope this helps

Comment: That is not it. Client is a part of a module, not a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

you get this error cause you are not using the json format the `oauth2client` expects. The [module documentation](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.Credentials.new_from_json) of `new_from_json` says:

> class method new_from_json(json_data)[source] Utility class method to
>   instantiate a Credentials subclass from JSON.
>
> **Expects the JSON string to have been produced by to_json().**
>
> Parameters:   json_data – string or bytes, JSON from to_json().
>
> Returns:  An instance of the subclass of Credentials that was
>   serialized with to_json().

The key here is that it expects the json object you give it to be one that it produced as a serialised instance of the class. you cant just give it any arrbitrary json object and expect it to know what to do.

When you produce the JSON serialised credential object from the modules `to_json` method it will set the `_module` and `_class` data

```py
        # Add in information we will need later to reconstitute this instance.
        to_serialize['_class'] = curr_type.__name__
        to_serialize['_module'] = curr_type.__module__
```

the reason this is important is later when you try to do `new_from_json` it will execute this part of the code

```py
        # Find and call the right classmethod from_json() to restore
        # the object.
        module_name = data['_module']
```

This fails in your case since the json you are using isnt json credential object produced by the module. The reson this is important is that later in the code it will need to know which service_account object to return to you

```py
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        # TODO(issue 388): eliminate the circularity that is the reason for
        #                  this non-top-level import.
        from oauth2client import service_account
        data = json.loads(_helpers._from_bytes(json_data))

        # We handle service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials since it is a
        # possible return type of GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        if (data['_module'] == 'oauth2client.service_account' and
                data['_class'] == 'ServiceAccountCredentials'):
            return service_account.ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json(data)
        elif (data['_module'] == 'oauth2client.service_account' and
                data['_class'] == '_JWTAccessCredentials'):
            return service_account._JWTAccessCredentials.from_json(data)
```

Long story short you cant give this any old json and expect it to work you will need to first create your credentials object in the class then call its to_json method to then serialise that object to be able to use it later to just load credentials from storage.

Comment: If I were to take the json google gave me and I were to put it through the json command, would that work?

Comment: you would need to create an oauth2client connection providing it any authentication / key / login details, once you  have a valid oauth2client connection that works you can then call that `to_json` on that instance and it will serialise your data to a json file which you can then use in future to just load the connection without proiding all the info manually

Comment: but it should be noted that if this is new code your building oauth2client is deprecated and the github page suggest other libarays to be used https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html

Comment: Really? That is annoying, because I don't know what to do now.

Comment: from the github page of oauth2client `oauth2client is now deprecated. No more features will be added to the libraries and the core team is turning down support. We recommend you use google-auth and oauthlib`

Comment: it wont stop working. its never good to start building new code with library which are deprecated. There are several reasons for this. if there becomes a security issue discovered no one will fix it. if server side they change the implementation your client will no longer work and no one will fix it. If you have an issue or cant get something to work there will be very few people using this so very few people even available to answer your question like you might have seen with this question. There is really no reason to start using this module when there are other modules out there in support

Comment: Are we at the point where I should redesign the whole code, or just authentication.
If this is stupid, blame my brain at night. 

Also, asking because I won't have more chances in the morning cus i cant be bothered

Comment: this is why we use modules, and why good code deisgn is important so you can swap out modules without to much of a code redesign or refactor. You need to look at the other modules like google-auth and oauthlib and see how they work. there will be many examples of people using these for google authentication so just see what they do and then factor that into your existing code to replace your oauth2client stuff

Answer (score 0):

Using `pydrive` and `oauth2client` to authenticate, you can use the following:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive    
from oauth2client.file import client


gauth = GoogleAuth()
cred = <content from `credentials.json`(string)>
gauth.credentials = client.Credentials.new_from_json(cred)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

If you already have a `credentials.json`, there should not be a need for a `client_secrets.json`.